# How can I force expire assume role to back my current account account store the data into my current account s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sts

I have one lambda from which I am accessing one cross account by assume role

```
sts = boto3.client('sts')
sts.assume_role(RoleArn='A', RoleSessionName='aaa')
```

Now I did some operation after accessing this

Like I get some instance information .

```
  ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
  desc = ec2.describe_instaces() #this all are  working fine
```

Now I want to back my lambda role(B) and store this data.

```
 sts2 = boto3.client('sts')
 sts2.assume_role(RoleArn='B', RoleSessionName='bbb')
```

and want to store `desc` those instance data into one s3 bucket of my current lambda account.

I tried these but it is not able to store  the data...Is there any way I can able to force expire the assume role and get my current access role to store the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an IAM Role is assigned to an AWS Lambda function, a set of temporary credentials will be automatically provided to the function. The code within the function can then use these credentials simply by calling AWS services, eg:

```
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
```

When you assume a role, a new set of credentials is returned.

```
response = sts.assume_role(RoleArn='A', RoleSessionName='aaa')
```

The `response` will then contain:

```
{
    'Credentials': {
        'AccessKeyId': 'string',
        'SecretAccessKey': 'string',
        'SessionToken': 'string',
        'Expiration': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    },
    'AssumedRoleUser': {
        'AssumedRoleId': 'string',
        'Arn': 'string'
    },
    'PackedPolicySize': 123
}
```

If you wish to use those *assumed credentials* in a subsequent call to AWS, you will need to create a `Session` object and then use that `Session` to create a new `Client`:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                  aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                  aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

assumed_client = session.client('ec2')
instances_response = assumed_client.describe_instances()
```

**Bottom line:** Calling `assume-role` does not actually change your credentials. Rather, you need use the returned credentials to create a new client object. Therefore, there is no concept of "expiring" any credentials.

Comment: great now if I want to put the data of instances in account of rolearn 'B" then I no need to do assume role of my account B am I right as account of rolearn B where my lambda iis running

Comment: Yes. If your Lambda function is running in Account B, then there is no need to assume a role. The code will automatically use the role that was assigned to the Lambda function.